# typeof in IE<=8 for native functions

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a variable obj

obj can be anything, and I want to detect if obj is a function. Normally I would do

```
typeof obj === 'function'
```

The problem is in IE <= 8 when obj is a native function (at least know it happens with window.open and window.alert). In IE typeof obj when object is window.open === 'object'

**Is there a reliable way to check if window.open is actually a function or not?**

I see jQuery also fails on this

```
$.isFunction(window.open) => false //in IE
```

this apperantly got removed in jquery 1.3 or something, not sure how they tested it before that.

**Added:**
One way seem to be to call

```
Function.prototype.apply.apply(window.open)
```

If this does not throw an error, then window open is a function. If you do

```
Function.prototype.apply.apply({})
```

Then IE throws an error "Function expected". But it is hardly a good solution to open a window to check if a variable is a function..

Comment: So this is just an issue for native functions in IE returning typeof object, but user defined functions are returning typeof function? Why is it not sufficient to just check that the native function exists i.e `window.open!==undefined`? Why do you need the native functions, which are documented to do this? Sorry just trying to understand your thought process.

Comment: Take a look @ 1.2 & its test for the "function" literal; http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/downloads/detail?name=jquery-1.2.js

Comment: ^ Relevant code from @AlexK.'s link `return !!fn && typeof fn != "string" && !fn.nodeName && fn.constructor != Array && /function/i.test( fn + "" );` where fn is the function name

Comment: @Scott it's because obj is unknown to my code, but I want a way to check if it's a function, even the functions that IE reports as objects that are native.

Comment: @AlexK. Anyone have any idea why they removed it? Returning wrong in certain situations? I can confirm it works in my situation at least.

Comment: I like the comment from John (Resig I presume): // This may seem like some crazy code, but trust me when I say that this is the only cross-browser way to do this. --John

Comment: Nope, but there is some comment & an issue number in the 1.3 source when it was replaced (replace 1.2/1.3 in the url above)

Comment: I'm thinking it can't be done reliably in IE, as the note here (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isFunction/) says `Note: As of jQuery 1.3, functions provided by the browser like alert() and DOM element methods like getAttribute() are not guaranteed to be detected as functions in browsers such as Internet Explorer.` which is the reason for removing it from jQuery 1.3. So if the community behind jQuery can't solve this, it's unlikely to have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to native browser functions, feature detection should be sufficient:

```
if (window.open) {
    window.open(...)
}
```

If someone overwrites native functions, then don't use their code. They shouldn't be doing this, and you are asking for problems.

It's also difficult to answer this question without some context. You are passing in `obj` and invoking it as a function. If you are passing in multiple data types and doing something different based on the type, I would argue that you shouldn't be handing functions here. Because of browser quirks, create a function explicitly to dynamically call another function and don't do error checking.

Comment: I honestly don't remember anymore what the reason for asking this was.